# Multiple file compilation in visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++

I have a very specific question in regards to visual C++ 2010 express. I have looked everywhere but can't find instructions on how to compile several source files. I have programmed on Unix at the command line and am trying to learn visual C++ 2010. I am using a header file that contains the function declarations and global variables. I don't know if this is the correct venue to ask this question but if anyone knows of some place where I can get the answer I would be grateful

Thanks,
Ral

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project that you build from the command line with a makefile, then the Visual Studio development environment will not recognize your project. To open and build your project using Visual Studio, first create an empty project containing the appropriate build settings using the Makefile Project Wizard. You can then use this project to build your project from the Visual Studio development environment.

The project displays no files in Solution Explorer. The project specifies the build settings, which are reflected in the project's property page.

The output file that you specify in the project has no effect on the name that the build script generates; it declares only an intention.

**Source:** [Creating a Makefile Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx.aspx) (*VS2013*)

Answer (score 0):

On the menu: File->New->Project

On the dialog:

- select Win32 Console Application,
- enter Name ( like you did in the -o in unix) in the bottom,
- and press OK

On the next dialog: Press next.

On the next dialog:

- unmark Precompiled headers
- mark Empty project
- press Finish

Now find the Solution Explorer tree. You have Solution name and a project with the same name in it.

- Right click on the project (not solution)
- choose Add->Existing Item
- and select your files, (you can copy them to the opened folder and then choose them)
- press Add

Now you can try to compile.